# What happens to properties after the final mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What happens if I

> Kill Trevor or Michael in the final mission?

Will someone else inherit their property and cars or will it all be lost?

Comment: Wait, so that choice to kill someone actually is a choice? I did the third option, but i assumed that there would be some interruption or other interference that would lead to a reconciliation before the finale if you choose a kill option. I mean, wouldn't killing someone lead to being unable to get 100% completion?

Comment: @Nzall Good question, but I think only a minority is after this goal. :) So bringing in this decision may make the others happy.

Answer (score 2):

no-one gets anything

the money from the final mission is split if you

> kill trevor, but not by killing michael, as his family gets the money.

but cars properties all that, no-one else gets that.